# JSP: How to pass array of object from servlet to JSP

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

How can I pass the array of object (Mcq[] mcq) from servlet to JSP? How can I extract the data from array of object using taglib in jsp?

CLASS:

```
public class Mcq {
private String question;
private String choice_1;
private String choice_2;

/* GETTERS AND SETTERS */
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
String question, choice_1, choice_2;
Mcq[] mcq = new Mcq[100];

for(int i=0; i<mcqCount; i++){
    question = request.getParameter("mcq-question-"+i);
    choice_1 = request.getParameter("mcq-choice-"+i);
    choice_2 = request.getParameter("mcq-choice-"+i);
    mcq[i].setQuestion(question);
    mcq[i].setChoice_1(choice_1);
    mcq[i].setChoice_2(choice_2);
}

request.getSession().setAttribute("mcq", mcq);      
RequestDispatcher dispatcher;
dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("testpage.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

HTML (testpage.jsp):

```
<body>
    <h1>           
        Question: ${mcq.getQeustion()}
        Choice-1: ${mcq.getChoice_1()}
        Choice-2: ${mcq.getChoice_2()}
    </h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>    
    <body>
        <h1>
            <c:forEach var="mcq" items="${mcq}">
                Question: ${mcq.question}
                Choice-1: ${mcq.choice_1}
                Choice-2: ${mcq.choice_2}
            </c:forEach>
        </h1>
   </body>
```

The EL "${mcq}" expression should be able to grab the Mcq's already because you have them set as a session attribute.